# How to delete a firebase user from Flutter app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a admin app (Flutter app) . I want to delete a firebase user by UID or Email address from my admin app.

Or Automatically in the Firebase a function that will delete the firebase user after n days days . Like subscription

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a user account, call delete() on the user object.
Firebase User Delete Documentation [Delete()](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseUser/delete.html)

Comment: there is no delete() function on Flutter

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseUser/delete.html

Comment: @SASaharukh I don't believe this answer is correct. A user cannot delete other users in an app, they can only delete themselves. The method in this answer deletes the currently authenticated user and then logs them out and will not delete users by their UID

Comment: As stated before, it only works when the user itself wants to delete data. Not for a admin user.